# Review count not work on search page

Tags: bigcommerce, stencil-component

I placed this Code on card.html, review count is not work only search page.

```html
{{#if show_rating}}
   <p class="card-text" data-test-info-type="productRating"> 
      <span class="rating--small"> 
         {{> components/products/ratings rating=rating}}
      </span>
      <span class="productView-reviewLink">
         {{#if rating '>' 0}} 
             <a href="{{url}}#product-reviews"> 
                 {{lang 'products.reviews.link_to_review' total=num_reviews}}
             </a>
         {{else}}
             {{lang 'products.reviews.link_to_review' total=num_reviews}} 
         {{/if}}
     </span> 
   </p> 
{{/if}}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain this a bit better? Is it only working on the search page or not?

Comment: It is not work on search page.